# Importing a gtlf file pops up a traceback error

Tags: modeling

What do I do with this? I was trying to import a gtlf file to the Blender, but it always pops a traceback like this but I don't know why it does this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 900, in execute
    return self.import_gltf2(context)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 914, in import_gltf2
    if self.unit_import(path, import_settings) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 924, in unit_import
    from .blender.imp.gltf2_blender_gltf import BlenderGlTF
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .gltf2_blender_scene import BlenderScene
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_scene.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .gltf2_blender_node import BlenderNode
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .gltf2_blender_mesh import BlenderMesh
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_mesh.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .gltf2_blender_material import BlenderMaterial
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ACE COMBAT 7\Game\Content\Paks\mod creations\ac7tools\blender-2.83.18-candidate+v283.5f156291cdcc-windows.amd64-release\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_material.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .gltf2_blender_KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness import pbr_specular_glossiness

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'io_scene_gltf2.blender.imp.gltf2_blender_KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a broken install of the gltf importer. It's not finding pieces of itself.  I would suggest obtaining a clean copy of the [Kronos code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO); removing the current importer; deleting its files; and installing the new importer following their instructions.